# What advice to give when OP doesn't follow up?

Tags: discussion

It looks like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261597/i-cannot-install-ubuntu-server-12-10-the-installer-hangs-at-the-language-select) the OP doesn't follow up with information. Should I advise jonas, who has offered a bounty on this question to either

- post his own question

or

- edit the question (difficult, he has not enough rep)

or

- do something completely different?

Comment: A user of more than 300 rep. can not edit a question? I know that the edit will be added to the review queue but he can do it.

Comment: @Lucio, having to go through the review process makes it a little difficult to quickly provide the required information - I am sure you remember that :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Jonas isn't the original asker (OP) he:

- Won't get notifications of new answers or comments
- Will have trouble adding information to the question because his edits will have to go through review.

In view of this I think Jonas should ask a new question and, as soon as he gets an answer, we should dupe the old question to the new answered one. This will make the process a whole lot easier for both Jonas *and* anyone trying to answer his question.

Comment: thx, Seth, you confirmed my primary intention - suggest posted.

Comment: @guntbert I also suggest that you custom flag the question and ask a moderator to refund the bounty, linking to your question here. That way the 50 rep won't go to waste.

Comment: Done and done :-)

Comment: @RolandiXor Thank you.